# What's wrong with this find condition

Tags: php, cakephp

The following works, it gives me all data where deleted is null:

```
$conditions = array('OR' => array(

    'Task.deleted' => null,


    )

);


$this->set('tasks', $this->Task->find('all', array('recursive' => 2, 'conditions' => $conditions)));
```

Similiar the following gives me all data where deleted is 0

```
$conditions = array('OR' => array(

 'Task.deleted' => 0,


)

); //...
```

But If i combine it like the following, it gives me the data where deleted is null, but not where deleted is 0.

```
$conditions = array('OR' => array(

        'Task.deleted' => 0,
        'Task.deleted' => null

        )

);
```

Comment: Don't know this standard but it looks that you are overwriting `0` with `null` here. Check if `'Task.deleted' => (0, null)` works ( or something like that )

Comment: This only gives me back the data where deleted is 0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to set the PHP array key `'Task.deleted'` twice, overwriting it. Do either of the following:

```
'Task.deleted' => array(0, null)
```

or:

```
'OR' => array(
    array('Task.deleted' => 0),
    array('Task.deleted' => null)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Read this

http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/1030/Complex-Find-Conditions

or

```
$conditions = array(
    'OR' => array(
       array('Task.deleted' => 0),
      array('Task.deleted' => null)
    )
    );

$this->set('tasks', $this->Task->find('all', array('recursive' => 2, 'conditions' => $conditions)));
```